# Hide R code in shiny executable

Tags: encryption, shiny, executable

I am new to shiny. I have ui and server file. I have packaged my R code, portable R and portable chrome into an executable. I want to distribute the executable to others. How can I hide the R code in ui.r and server.r files?

I want to distribute as desktop app as exe file. So that user should be able to run by just clicking the executable.

Comment: Might be able to do it on `shinyapps.io`. Not sure.

Comment: Not sure about hiding the R code but to distribute as a desktop app you could have a look at [this](http://blog.analytixware.com/2014/03/packaging-your-shiny-app-as-windows.html) link

Comment: I have seen this link and able to package as well to an exe. However, when user executes the exe, it unzips the code to a folder and anyone can see the code. I want the code should be unreadable format and not simple R file where we can view the source code.

Comment: R is really a research tool, so they are disinclined to hide anything (except symbolic debugging information apparently). I don't think you are going to find anything. If you want to hide stuff, maybe you need to look at SAS or Matlab who are more inclined to worry about such things.